# Uninstall XC9 Update 2 without uninstalling XM environment

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I would like to uninstall `XC9 Update 2` from our dev environment. I am finding scripts that allow me to remove the commerce databases and web sites, but I am not finding anything about removing the installed assets from the content management environment.

**NOTE:** I do not want to remove the CM web site or databases; I just want to remove XC components.

I could remove the obvious items such as commerce templates and config files, but I would prefer an accurate list of items to remove. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky one, there is no uninstall script for items as they're just db records. The installation package could have created a new item, or updated field values on an existing item, and you'll have to carefully choose the rollback procedure in each case.

The simplest option in this case is to stand up a new XM environment with clean databases and resync your content back out of Unicorn/TDS.

If you don't want to go down that path, you could look inside each of the packages that are installed for XC and see the items are represented as files. You could use that data to manually go and rollback the changes one by one but it would likely be a painful and time consuming exercise.